# a+ file permission in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I opened a File in Matlab using the a+ permission to read and write, and append data to end of file. I am able to write and append data to the file properly, but I am not able to read. 
Though the file permission definition says reading and writing, I am not able to read. Can you please help me here? Anybody encountered this problem?

```
    fid = fopen('E:\code folder\Translation values.txt','a+')
    [Array] = fscanf(fid,'%f %f')
```

The array returned is empty. same is the problem with textscan as well. The Cell array is empty. But when I change the permission to r+, it works fine. Please help me.

Comment: Text mode (if you are on Windows)? `fopen("...", "at+")`?

Comment: yes I did. but it doesn't append. Just writes over the text present, if file opened again after fclose.

Comment: I used at+ as well. It doesn't work when am reading. It returns empty data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flag `a+` stands for "append and read", thus, the file position indicator pointer probably points to the end of the file. If so, you might need to call `fseek` or `frewind` before reading.